# Conditional orderBy

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm building a filter function in a project.

I have a filter option "Show newest", "Show oldest" and a bunch of other options. I found a way how to implement conditional where clauses, but there doesn't seems to be a conditional orderBy class.

My conditional where clause looks like this:

```
$query->where(function($query) use ($request){
   if( ! empty($request->input('prices')) ){
      $opts = $request->prices;
      $query->where('price_id', $opts[0]);
   }
})
```

Is there a way to do this with a ->orderBy too?

**UPDATE**

```
return Auction::where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now() )
         ->where('locale', $locale)
         ->where('sold', 0)
         ->where(function($query) use ($request){

             if( ! empty($request->input('prices')) ){
                  $opts = $request->prices;
                  $query->where('price_id', $opts[0]);
             }
         })->paginate(8);
```

How can I do it in the eloquent-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can do it this way:

```
if ($request->input('id_desc')) {
   $query = $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

or you can do it this way:

```
$columns = ['id','name',]; // here define columns you allow for sorting
$orderBy = ['ASC', DESC'];


$column = $request->input('order_by_column');
$type = $request->input('order_by_type');

if (!in_array($column, $columns)) {
  $column = 'id';
}
if (!in_array($type , $orderBy )) {
  $type = 'ASC';
}

$query = $query->orderBy($column, $type);
```

**EDIT**

Using your code:

```
$query = Auction::where('end_date', '>', Carbon::now() )
         ->where('locale', $locale)
         ->where('sold', 0)
         ->where(function($query) use ($request){

             if( ! empty($request->input('prices')) ){
                  $opts = $request->prices;
                  $query->where('price_id', $opts[0]);
             }
         });


if ($request->input('id_desc')) {
    $query = $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}

return $query->paginate(8);
```

Comment: @RW24 Please look at the new answer

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Looks logic now! Is this a good practice for a filter functionality? Or should you do it differently?

Comment: That's fine but as I showed you should probably create some kind of "whitelist" and allow user only filtering by those fields in case field name is sent in input